# Do I need to modify Web. xml after creating new package

Tags: eclipse, rest, web.xml, webservice-client

I am creating REST webservices on Eclipse. So, I have one login webservice and other is registration webservice.  Now,  when these both webservices are in same package,  they are working great.  But when I put one of them into another package,  Error 404 occurs for the one which I put in the new package.

Do I need to make changes in web.xml? 
Please help. And ask for more information, if required.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what REST implementation you are using. If you are using a standard annotation-based implementation, there should be no reason to have to update your web.xml. Just make sure your annotations specify unique mappings. Check your console in Eclipse when the application is published to see if there were any issues at startup.